# System.IO.IOException: 'Bad file name or number'

Tags: vb.net

I have this string and I am trying to write it with FileSystem.Write and I keep getting this error of 'Bad file name or number'.

```
sline = FormName + "|" + OrderNo + "|" + BatchNo + "|" + OpusOverlay + "|" 
+ Overlay + "|" + Type + "|" + Numbered + "|" + NeedPDF + 
Constants.vbCrLf;
            FileSystem.Write(1, sline);
```

What could be the cause of this? Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Missing or incorrect FileSystem.Open() call, typically.  Do not use these methods, they were meant only to port old VB code that was written twenty years ago.  Use StreamWriter instead.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  [check this out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

An example of what Hans was referring

```
Using strw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Path+file.ext)
    strw.Write(sline)
End Using
```